# JS callback for ratchet popover closing

Tags: javascript, html, ratchet-2

I have a `ratchet` popover in my page and I'd like run a `callback` after the popover closing.

The popover is like this:

```
<a href="popover" id="idLinkPopover" >

        <h1 class="title"> Title </span>
            <span class="icon icon-caret" >  </span> 
        </h1>

 </a>

<div id="popover" class="popover">
  <header class="bar bar-nav">
    <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
  </header>
  <ul class="table-view">
    <li class="table-view-cell" id="id1">Elem1</li>
    <li class="table-view-cell" id="id2">Elem2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
document.querySelector('#popover').addEventListener('onclick', function(e) {

       // ..........

}, false);
```

but it doesn't work and I don't it's the correct way to handle the popover closing because I used the `onclick` event.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`<li class="table-view-cell" id="id1" ontouchstart="alert(123)">Elem1</li>`

Comment: incredible answer buddy